# Custom Post Layout In Grid

Tags: php, wordpress

For my Wordpress-site I have the posts in a 3x grid. This is the code generating the output.

```
<div class="first-post">
           <?php if (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

           <!-- calling first the_post(); will step the loop forward -->

           <?php get_template_part('content','grid-firstpost'); ?>  
           <?php endif; ?> 
        </div>


        <div class="other-posts">
            <?php $i = 1; ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>                    
                <!-- the loop will be at the 2nd post here -->
                <?php get_template_part('content','grid'); ?>                                          
                <?php if ($i%3 == 0) : ?>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <?php endif; $i++; ?>

                <?php if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == '/' ): ?>
                <?php if ($i == 3): ?>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
                   <!-- calling the_post(); will step the loop forward -->
                   <?php get_template_part('content','grid-test'); ?>  
                   <?php if ($i%3 == 0) : ?>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <?php endif; $i++; ?>
                   <?php endif; ?> 
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php endif ?>

                <?php if ($i == 7): ?>
                    <div class="first-post">
                       <!-- making post 7 fullwidth -->
                       <?php get_template_part('content','grid-firstpost'); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif ?>


            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif; ?>  

        </div>
```

I have created a custom div for the third spot in the grid. The problem is that the post that should originally have that spot, are hided because of the custom div `(<?php if ($i == 3): ?>)`.

**So the output is like this:**

+Full width post+

First post      Second Post      **Custom Div**

*Fourth post*    Fifth Post         Sixth Post

**What it should be:**

+Full width post+

First Post    Second Post   **Custom Div**

*Third Post*   Fourth Post     Fifth Post

I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're incrementing the variable $i twice if it happens to be 3. Just increment it at the end of the while loop, so it remains stable for the duration of the loop.

```
<div class="other-posts">
  <?php $i = 1; ?>
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>                    

<!-- Style the grid post 3 with a custom div -->

    <?php if ($i == 3): ?>
      <?php get_template_part('content','grid-customdiv'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($i%3 == 0) : ?> 
      <div class="clearfix"></div> 
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php get_template_part('content','grid'); ?> 


    <?php $i++; ?>

  <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif; ?>  

</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The grid stop after the 3 post. The code is now updated.

Comment: Ok, answer edited. Try this - I think this is all you need

Comment: Almost maybe, it outputs the same result as the original code. The post that should be on spot 3 are hided.

Comment: So you actually want to output the third post twice - once with a custom layout and again with the normal layout?

Comment: Yes, that may work I think. What I have now, listen, the content in content-grid-customdiv.php are generating a Facebook Page Box. That box are always placed in the third position of the grid. The problem is, when doing that, the post that should have that spot are hided. That's because of the Facebook Page Box are taking control of that spot. The third post need to be in the fourth grid position. Hope that makes everything more clear.

Comment: Ok, answer edited. When `$i == 3`, the custom div should be printed, then the clearfix, then the normal third post content.

Comment: Magic! Works like a charm. Much appreciated! The only problem now is that the post 7 that should generate a full width post screw up the grid, and shows identical post on the fullwidth and in the grid itselfs. Is that because of the clearfix? Under the fullwidth of post 7 it should be 3 more posts side by side (x x x).